# Replacing plain strings in YAML config file with variables

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I'm working on a Java app with configuration stored in the application.yaml file, with endpoints defined as plain strings as follows:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      provider:
        keycloak:
          token-uri: path/to/somewhere
          authorization-uri: path/to/somewhere
          userinfo-uri: path/to/somewhere
```

And so on. The thing is, I don't like the idea of keeping the endpoints defined as plain strings here, I would strongly prefer to import them from somewhere else in the app, e.g. from a Java enum. But as far as I can see there is no real way to use variables in YAML, so what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholders like this:

```
app:
  name: "MyApp"
  description: "${app.name} is a Spring Boot application written by ${username:Unknown}"
```

See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) for reference